# Use the output of local-exec to fetch the ARN and use it as variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloud

Im using local-exec provisioner with AWS CLI command to create Amazon Interactive Video Service Channel. (AWS IVS)

```
   provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = "aws ivs create-channel --name test | tee test.txt"
   }
```

This is the content of test.txt:

```
channel:
  arn: arn:aws:ivs:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:channel/3ruIGo4qyo8t
  authorized: false
  ingestEndpoint: 5xxxxxxd29b.global-contribute.live-video.net
  latencyMode: LOW
  name: test
  playbackUrl: https://XXXXXX.us-east-1.playback.live-video.net/api/video/v1/us-east-1.XXXXXXXXXX.channel.3ruIGo4qyo8t.m3u8
  recordingConfigurationArn: ''
  tags: {}
  type: STANDARD
streamKey:
  arn: arn:aws:ivs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXX:stream-key/9QR0UjQPjtTK
  channelArn: arn:aws:ivs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX:channel/3ruIGo4qyo8t
  tags: {}
  value: sk_us-east-1_9QR0UjQPjtTK_8lx6Yy8mJfAUA0VP5fVHwAXL6cYl8u
```

Now I need to fetch the ARN and later use it as variable

```
resource "null_resource" "channelArn" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "export TF_VAR_channelArn=$(sed -n 's/channelArn: //p' test-channel.txt)"
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }
}
```

After `terraform apply` I can see that my command is successfully executed but when I `echo $TF_VAR_channelArn` it doesnt show anything. How can I get the channelArn from the local file and use it as aws_ssm_parameter?

Comment: Well, can you use `aws ivs` to fetch the arn?

Comment: Where do you "echo $TF_VAR_channelArn"? Your code does not show any such command.

Comment: The environment variable only exists in process, so you cannot assign and access the ARN in this manner. A good path forward would be to use the `yamldecode` function to access the ARN from the output text: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/yamldecode. We could assist further with more information in the question about the IVS provisioning.